# Google Play publish app

Tags: android, google-play

This is the first time i am going to publish an app for android in the Google Play Store and as you can imagine i am VERY green. My question is after submitting the app for aproval does it get published straight away if aproved or do i have the option to submitt the app on a certain time to the store? The reason is i have a database that feeds the app that needs to be updated but before i go live with the website as well i would like to know if the app will be aproved or not so i can plan my timming. I hope some experienced developers could shine some light on this...

Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

### **For timed publishing you can go through following steps.**

**Publish with timed publishing**

**Step 1: Turn on timed publishing**

1. Go to your Google Play Developer Console.
2. Select an app.
3. Near the top of the screen, select the publishing
   mode drop-down Drop-down arrow. By default, you'll see "Standard
   publishing."
4. Select Turn on timed publishing.
5. Review details about
   timed publishing, then click Turn on.
6. After you've made your update,click Submit update. Your update will be 
   processed as usual. This can take up to a few hours.
7. To review your update, click View change log.

**Step 2: publish your app update**

1. Once your update has been processed and you're ready to publish, select Go live.
2. Review the change log and select Go live. Your update will be live
   on Google Play within a few minutes.

   ### **How does timed publishing work?**

When you select timed publishing, your update needs to be processed before it can go live. Processing takes up to a few hours.

When your update is processed, you'll see a **Go live** button. When you select **Go live**, you'll make the update available on Google Play within a few minutes.

**Tip:** Timed publishing can be helpful if you want to publish an app update at a specific time for an [ad campaign](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6262700), launch event, or to coordinate a new APK release with changes to your app’s store listing or distribution.

**Important notes about timed publishing**

If you make changes to your app's **In-app Products** page while you're in timed publishing mode, they'll still be published immediately.
Timed publishing is only available for updates, not when publishing an app for the first time.
You can't revert changes made in timed publishing mode. This is particularly important when publishing new APKs and managing APK version codes.
Updates to alpha/beta APKs and all other updates, including updates submitted using the [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/#publishing), will be published only after you click **Go live**.

for more details visit :
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282?hl=en

Comment: ok thanks for the answer but does this button become available after aproval? Because i can not see such button... All i can see is publish app or save draft.. and i am afraid that if i click publish app and it get´s approved as expected it goes live straight awaw!

Comment: Yes. "Go Live" button will be available after approval.

Comment: After reading The docs "Go Live" button is only available for updates andar no for The first publishing of The app is that right?

Answer (score -2):

If your application is not some malware or virus then it will be aproved in a few hours 100% ... :)
But there is a delayed publish function .. Right up corner I think ...

Have a nice day :)

Comment: The approval/review/processing can and does take days sometimes.